# How to send DELETE request with body in Apache CXF JAX-RS with webclient?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, http-delete

I want to call `webclient.delete(deleteBody)` similar to POST.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(getUrl());
client = client.type("application/json").accept("application/json");
HTTPConduit conduit = WebClient.getConfig(client).getHttpConduit();
conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(getApiTimeout());
Response resp = client.post(postData);
```

but there is no method which takes deleteBody.

I even use `webclient.invoke("DELETE", deletBody)` but this throws 500 HTTP error.

Here is my delete body:

```
{"password":"1ad1ad","username":11111111}
```

But I tried with `curl` command for DELETE its working:

```
curl -q -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X DELETE -d @del.json http://d.eze.cc/api/pd/xxxxx/DEL001234/
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the CXF `WebClient` does not support sending a body in a `DELETE` request.

1. This is OK since it makes no sense to send a body with a `DELETE` request. See this question:  [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299628/647772)
2. For the `500` error you get please take a look into the server log. How is the server side REST implemented?